# How to interpret these (en|de)cryption instructions?

Tags: encryption

I found this string on a forum

```
HVrUyitih"fZnvWxbsQXrk6a61oxEWU0TvcagVKz1RvRTBbqpmuJ6zNWp5a5
ZO_ggA1ov6exdUTNREr"A5NthZt97Im60kBHn0sXUhwfN33ce5VvRfUItQyg
yH4EeQx"pIH5I6oaaYT3"IPn4lm_EuxfWN5xoOQRdaqttqvvC4c
```

together with these instructions on how it was encrypted.

```
ATOM-128 --> FERON-74 --> MEGAN-35 --> REVERSE --> RC4(OLOY)
```

These instructions are said to be "sufficient to decrypt", so I'm not asking to "break the security of a specific system", I just wanted to understand how that security was put together.

Comment: Requests for decryption of specific messages are too narrowly focused to be of value to anyone else, and are off-topic.

Comment: Noo I don't want it decrypted. I'm just wondering how it would work so I know for future reference on how to do it. I am just wondering what order, how to do it and what steps to take. I would rather somebody tell me how to do it than do it for me as then I'd never learn.

Comment: i really dont get how this stuff provides any kind of security but i think
this website will help you. http://crypo.in.ua/tools/

Comment: Ah.  Assuming your encryption chain is accurate, you need to decrypt it in the reverse order of `RC4(OLOY) -> REVERSE -> MEGAN-35 -> FERON-74 -> ATOM-128`. Your best bet is to find the program on the computer that created it, and from there, search for the key or password of whoever encrypted it.  I'm not even sure how it's encoded, because while it looks like base64, it has some non-base64 characters in the message.

Comment: I did it in reverse order from what he said it was and when I got to Megan-35 it stopped converting as it said it wasn't a Megan-35 string and same with Feron than Atom. I used crypo.in and other users used the same website and it decrypted successfully for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the algorithms used, just use them in reverse order.

Since you say,

```
ATOM-128 --> FERON-74 --> MEGAN-35 --> REVERSE --> RC4(OLOY)
```

then the answer should be, "apply RC4 decryption using 0L0Y as the key, then reverse the order of the bytes, apply MEGAN-35 decryption, and so on. There are several tools online that supply ready-to-use encryption and decryption.

There are also search engines that would find [this page](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131107154828AAPuYV7) for you.

The URL reported in that page is

```
h**p://ge.tt/api/1/files/53H5HXx/0/blob?download
```

which answers,

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
set-cookie: session=0!%7B%22storage%22%3A%7B%22used%22%3A0%2C%22free%22%3A250000000%2C%22extra%22%3A0%2C%22limit%22%3A250000000%7D%2C%22accesstoken%22%3A%22a.0.anon-[...]%22%2C%22unread%22%3A0%2C%22downloads%22%3A0%2C%22files%22%3A0%2C%22created%22%3A1385503952%2C%22type%22%3A%22anon%22%2C%22userid%22%3A%22anon-; path=/;
set-cookie: anon=0!%7B%22userid%22%3A%22anon-[...]; expires=Tue, 10 Dec 2013 22:11:57 GMT; path=/;
location: http://w255582.open.ge.tt/1/files/53H5HXx/0/blob?referer=&user=anon-[...]-&download=
Connection: close
```

By following the redirect, I get another redirect

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
location: http://w569658.blob2.ge.tt/streams/53H5HXx/Black%20puppet%20lite.rar?sig=[...]&type=download
connection: close
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

that downloads something called "Black Puppet Lite", a RAR archive

```
 Attributes      Size    Date   Time   Name
----------- ---------  -------- -----  ----
    ..A....    494080  06-11-13 21:20  Black puppet lite/Black Puppet.exe
    ..A....     17920  15-10-13 21:06  Black puppet lite/IconChanger.dll
    ..A....    272896  25-08-13 13:23  Black puppet lite/Mono.Cecil.dll
    ...D...         0  06-11-13 21:22  Black puppet lite
----------- ---------  -------- -----  ----
               784896                  4
```

The file has already been analyzed by [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/it/file/c3ec23d3b4e078051ecfa8fae6a612cf09f86a696dbb0973e47bff10ac7a4391/analysis/) on 2013-11-23 11:42:31, when it was called `file-6246346.exe`. Which makes my spider sense tingle.

A sandbox analysis of the file is [here](https://malwr.com/analysis/M2Q5N2U2MWJiZDgxNDE4ZGIxZjNiODU3ZWViMWYzNDc/#summary_keys). Apparently it does nothing evil, or it does nothing *too soon*.

The two accompanying DLLs (MonoCecil and IconChanger) apparently are tools to manipulate executables, changing their assemblies and icons - so, among the other things, allowing them to masquerade as something else.

The file was apparently developed by someone calling himself *Shade*, and the executable itself has reference to "Divine Miner", as well as a copyright from Hewlett-Packard Company that is almost certainly bogus, since nowhere in HP can a reference be found to either puppets, or miners.

The two words, the shadiness of the article and the references to cryptographic functions inside the executable bring me to a wild-ass guess, that this thing is some sort of Bitcoin-mining slave puppet application.

Comment: Hmm I didn't realize the KeyPass had to be OLOY I think thats where I went wrong, just a bit of miscommunication on my side but I still tried it with OLOY and it didn't work. Not sure what went wrong, is it zero or O?

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I put it with a zero, tried with the letter O and it worked :) Thanks man! I learn something new everyday, and I'm not sure I just always wanted to learn decryption and I found this string on Hackforums with the order.

Comment: You might be interested in a Cryptography course on Coursera (www.coursera.org) - the level I course starts from basic stuff and is quite interesting (some programming required).